# Groovy range iteration without parenthesis

Tags: groovy

The following Groovy code prints a range of numbers from 1 to 5.

```
(1..5).each {println it}
```

However, when I forget to add the parenthesis, and do this:

```
1..5.each { println it}
```

It prints only 5

Why is this legal Groovy syntax? I would expect this to either behave as the (1..5) version or to throw an exception saying that I have forgotten the parenthesis.

Comment: `.each` probably binds stronger than `..`, so your second command is equivalent to `1..(5.each { println it})` where the range is unused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`5.each` has priority over `1..5` in the Groovy parser. It works because it is doing something like this:

```
ret = 5.each { println it }
range = 1..ret
assert range == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The return of `each` is the collection itself

Answer (score 4):

The `.`-Operator has a higher precedence in groovy than `..` [Source](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/JN2535-Control):

> **Operator Overloading**
>
> The precedence heirarchy of the operators, some of which we haven't looked at yet, is, from highest to lowest:
>   $(scope escape)
>
> ```
>   new ()(parentheses)
>   [](subscripting) ()(method call) {}(closable block) [](list/map)
>   . ?. *. (dots)
>   ~ ! $ ()(cast type)
>   **(power)
>   ++(pre/post) --(pre/post) +(unary) -(unary)
>   * / %
>   +(binary) -(binary)
>   << >> >>> .. ..<
>   < <= > >= instanceof in as
>   == != <=>
>   &
>   ^
>   |
>   &&
>   ||
>   ?:
>   = **= *= /= %= += -= <<= >>= >>>= &= ^= |=
> ```